# How can I translate "jumpcut"?

Tags: translation

I personally was going with *detranĉaĵo*. Is that a correct translation of *jumpcut*? What other, or more correct, translation could I use?

Comment: Parenteze, mi scivolemas pri kial vi volas scii? Ĉu vi tradukas film-softvaron eble?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Detranĉaĵo* is a little bit general. Without context I would think of a slice of bread that's cut of a loaf.

Film making terminology in Esperanto is not really well developed AFAICS. For jump cut you could actually use a litteral translation so *salttranĉo*.

However it turns out that in Esperanto you usually don't talk about cutting but about gluing when it comes to film or audio editing. For gluing two film or sound snippets together you use the verb "munti".

So one candidate would be *saltmunto* or maybe *interrompa munto*.